# Vertical to Horizontal Sub-Menus

Tags: css, menu, submenu

On my website at twoguysplayingzelda.com, my sub-menus (desktop view) are currently displayed vertically and I would like to change it to horizontal. When a user hovers over the tab "GAMES", I would like the sub-menu to stretch horizontally almost like a 2nd menu bar with all the games. My menu CSS code is as below. Thanks for any help!

```
div.navigation.section.no-padding.bg-dark { 
    background: #616161;
}

.main-menu {        
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;   
    font-size: 1.0em;   
    text-align: center;
}       

.main-menu li { position: relative; }       

.main-menu > li { float: left; }        

.main-menu > li:before {        
    content: none;  
    display: block; 
    position: absolute; 
    right: 0;   
    top: 50%;   
    margin-top: -18px;  
    margin-right: -13px;    
}       

.main-menu > li:last-child:before { content: none; }        

.main-menu > li > a {       
    display: block; 
    padding-top: 12px;  
    padding-bottom: 12px;   
    padding-left: 12px; 
    padding-right: 12px;    
    font-size: 1.0em;   
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    text-transform: uppercase;  
    letter-spacing: 1px;    
    font-weight: 400;
}       

.main-menu > li:first-child > a { margin-left: 0; }     

.main-menu > .has-children > a,     
.main-menu > .page_item_has_children > a { padding-right: 12px; position: 
relative; }     

.main-menu > .has-children > a::after,      
.main-menu > .page_item_has_children > a::after {       
    content: "";    
    display: none;
    border: 5px solid transparent;      
    border-top-color: #999; 
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 1001;  
    right: 29px;    
    top: 50%;   
    margin-top: -2px;   
}       

.main-menu li:hover > a { 
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #01B3D9;  
    color: #FFFFFF; }       

.main-menu > .has-children:hover > a::after,        
.main-menu > .page_item_has_children:hover > a::after { border-top-color: 
#fff; }
```

/* Sub menus --------------------------------------- */

```
.main-menu li ul {      
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 10000; 
    display: block; 
    left: -9999px;  
    top: 10px;  
    -webkit-opacity: 0; 
    -moz-opacity: 0;    
    opacity: 0; 
    z-index: 999;   
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out, top 0.3s ease-in-out; 
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out, top 0.3s ease-in-out;    
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out, top 0.3s ease-in-out; 
    -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out, top 0.3s ease-in-out;  
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out, top 0.3s ease-in-out; 
}       

.is_mobile .main-menu li ul {       
    -webkit-opacity: 1; 
    -moz-opacity: 1;    
    opacity: 1; 
    display: none;  
}       

.main-menu > li > ul { padding-top: 20px; }     

.main-menu ul li {      
    float: none;        
    display: block;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.075);              
}       

.main-menu ul li:first-child { border-top: none; }      

.main-menu ul > .has-children::after,       
.main-menu ul > .page_item_has_children::after {        
    content: "";
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    display: block; 
    border: 6px solid transparent;  
    border-left-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);   
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 1001;  
    right: 10px;    
    top: 50%;   
    margin-top: -5px;   
}       

.main-menu ul > .has-children:hover::after,
.main-menu ul > .page_item_has_children:hover::after { border-left-color: 
#fff; }             

.main-menu ul li {      
    display: block; 
    width: 240px;   
    background: #616161;    
}       

.main-menu ul a {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.0em;
    background: #616161;    
    display: block; 
    text-align: left;   
    font-weight: 400;   
    padding: 3px;   
    padding-left: 12px; 
    line-height: 130%;  
    color: #FFFFFF; 
}       

.main-menu ul a:hover {         
    background: #01B3D9;
    color: #FFFFFF; 
}       

.main-menu li:hover > ul {      
    -webkit-opacity: 1; 
    -moz-opacity: 1;    
    opacity: 1; 
    left: 138.25%;  
    margin-left: -120px;    
    top: 20.44px;   
}       

.is_mobile .main-menu li:hover ul { display: block; }       


/* Deep down --------------------------------------- */     


.main-menu ul li ul { 
    top: 5px; 
}       

.main-menu ul li:hover > ul {       
    top: 0; 
    left: 240px;    
    margin-left: 0; 
}       

.main-menu ul ul li { background: #3d3d3d; }        
.main-menu ul ul ul li { background: #4d4d4d; }     
.main-menu ul ul ul ul li { background: #4d4d4d; }
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, your games submenu will be too large to show horizontally.

Here's how you could do it though.

Delete this:

```
.main-menu li {
    position: relative;
}
```

And add this

```
.main-menu li ul.sub-menu {
    display: flex; 
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow-x: auto;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Should look like:

[image]

You can also add

```
.main-menu li ul.sub-menu {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Which will give you this:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure exactly how it would look. I'll need to play around with some ideas but I agree with you on it being too large right now. I updated the CSS. When I hover over games, the sub-menu flickers really bad and I am not able to click on any links. Any idea what could be causing that? I've left the issue on the website so you are able to check it out. Thanks for your help!